# Is that possible to move a section in tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to move sections in tableview. I googled about this i did't find any document about that. Any documentation or sample codes will be helpful. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean change the order that the sections are in, or actually move them while the app is running?

Comment: @hpiOSCoder i saw one video in wwdc uitable tricks he really move the section using this method [self.tableView moveSection:0 toSection:2];

Comment: lets discuss this in chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10882/ios-jail

Comment: The code you posted, [self.tableView moveSection:0 toSection:2]; is all you need to do.

Comment: @rdelmar yeah, I know it was, but i want know about that what is really happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these functions in the UITableView class:

```
– insertSections:withRowAnimation:
– deleteSections:withRowAnimation:
– moveSection:toSection:
```

They are well documented in the official API docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/moveSection:toSection:

Comment: Note: the moveSection:toSection: method is available in iOS 5 only